# How To Set No Animation For UIViewController Segue In Interface Builder?

Tags: ios8, interface-builder, xcode6, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm presenting a modal UIViewController but I don't want any "Cover Vertical" animation.  In interface Builder there is no option for Transition Style to none only 4 options - Cover Vertical, Flip Horizontal, Cross Dissolve, Partial Curl.

How can I disable cover vertical animation for one segue in IB?